# Find out when UIWebView title changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

Is there a way to find out when the content inside a `UIWebView` changes title?

Example:

I have a UIWebView, and its content changes rather frequently through JavaScript, so I can't rely on the `webViewDidFinishLoading` method. Is there a way to call a specific selector or function when the title changes?

**Update:** Here is my current approach, it works, but does not seem to be optimal:

```
if(syncTitle){
    var updatePageTitleTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("syncPageTitle"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}
```

Comment: If you switch to use `WKWebView` in nowadays, you can use the `title` property with KVO.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test the code below, but it should work

First you need to be able to listen for callbacks from js:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
     if([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"titlechange"])
     {
       //Title was changed...
       return NO; //make sure the window location is not actually changed..
     }
     return YES;
}
```

After that you need to call this on your webview. It creates an update listener for the title property of your document.

```
[YOUR_WEBVIEW stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.onpropertychange = function() {if (window.event.propertyName == 'title') {window.location = 'titlechanged://tralala';}};"];
```

**UPDATE**

```
[YOUR_WEBVIEW stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var target = document.querySelector('head > title');var observer = new window.WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {        window.location = 'titlechanged://tralala';});});observer.observe(target, { subtree: true, characterData: true, childList: true });"];
```

Comment: I think this is the only clean way.

Comment: The document.onpropertychange function appears to not be called on iOS browsers. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to cause a server error. How do you think that Safari tells when the page title changes?